# Infinite Loop when looping through FileInputStream

Tags: java, infinite-loop, fileinputstream

Alright, so I am writing a Java application to import a csv file and then loop through the results, and load them into an array. I am importing the file correctly because it doesn't through an Exception. My issues is that when I try to count the number of records in the FileInputStream I am trapped in an infinite loop. What could be the issue here. Heres the code:

This is my class with a Main method which calls go():

```
public void go() {
    pop = new PopularNames();
    popGui = new PopularNamesGui();
    String file = popGui.userInput("Enter the correct name of a file:");
    pop.setInputStream(file);
    pop.getNumberOfNames();
}
```

This is the class PopularNames (pop), and in the below method I am setting the inputStream var to a new FileINputStream. The file name is provided by the user.

```
public void setInputStream(String aInputStream) {
    try {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(aInputStream));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("The file was not found.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This is the trouble method. Where I am simply looping through the FileInputStream and counting the number of records:

```
public void getNumberOfNames() {
    while (this.inputStream.hasNext()) {
        fileDataRows++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to use the name `inputStream` for something which is actually a `Scanner`. It makes it very confusing when you don't see the declaration for a while, and just see method calls which aren't valid on an actual `InputStream`. Likewise `aInputStream` sounds like it should actually be `filename` or something similar.

Comment: What Jon said (+1), but I would rephrase as "it's a **REALLY** bad idea" to not follow sensible naming standards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public void getNumberOfNames() {   
  while (this.inputStream.hasNext()) {   
     inputStream.nextLine(); // Need to read it so that we can go to next line if any
     fileDataRows++;    
  } 
}
```

Comment: Agree. See also http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next() regarding next() and hasNext()

Comment: This did work... however when I went to read the file into an array, (in another method), I got an error that said: No line found... why?

Comment: I just need to know how many lines are in the file, so that I can appropriately set the size of an array. Thats what getNumberOfNames is trying to accomplish...

Comment: The reason you need to call the nextLine() is that reading of the file isn't progressing with just a hasNext() call.

Comment: @Walter: use `java.util.ArrayList` insteadof array. then you don't need to know the size

Comment: That is what I thought. I guess I just need to start a new scanner in that method, and then another new scanner else where in the class. Thanks for all the help!